# MySql 5.6: escaping consecutive percent signs in like query

Tags: mysql

Consider 2 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE NAME LIKE '%\%%';

SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE NAME LIKE '%\%\%%';
```

Assume that `T1` has records where `NAME` is `%`, `%%`, or `%%%`.

I would expect the second query to return fewer results but it is including the record where `T1.NAME = '%'`!  Is there a way to filter out that record using like query? Something like `SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE NAME LIKE '%\%\%%' AND NAME <> '%';` is not what I am looking for.

```
mysql> explain table1;
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| text  | varchar(4) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select * from table1
    -> where text like '%\%%';
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table1 | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select * from table1
    -> where text like '%\%\%%';
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table1 | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is my config if it helps:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=402653184
innodb_log_file_size=262144000
innodb_log_buffer_size=8388608
max_allowed_packet=5241856
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=20971520
```

I need to investigate further but it appears that the problem has something to do with the way that the database is being created:

```
create database testdb character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I was able to get the correct results when I create the database in a less specific way:

```
create database testdb;
```

Any idea why?

Comment: I was not able to replicate the problem. Your escaping seems fine. Can you please check this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38d9a/3 The second query returns fewer records, as expected. Can you please double check your data and queries?

Comment: How are you building your queries? Are you using PHP/Java/PDO/etc?

Comment: @bostaf, no denying that fiddle words works but I copy & pasted it into the mysql cli with the results that I describe:
`mysql> select * from table1`
`    -> where text like '%\%%';`
returns 
`4 rows in set (0.00 sec)`
and 
`mysql> select * from table1`
`    -> where text like '%\%\%%';`
returns
`4 rows in set (0.00 sec))`

Comment: @Salman-A  In the end it will be Java (and Hibernate...puke) but right now I am just trying fix these queries so really anything that works!  That mostly means MySql Workbench & mysql cli.

Comment: Can you run `explain table1` and update your question with its output? Also can you explain how are you building your queries (what's your client? command line? PHP? ...) as per @SalmanA's comment?

Comment: @gwadj the queries work perfectly in MySQL command line. If you were using some library I would check if query was passed through `stripslashes` or something similar. Having said that, try doubling the backslashes `%\\%\\%%`.

Comment: @SalmanA I have tried doubling the backslashes and this on different machines (mac & linux vm's) with the same bad results.  bostaf was kind enough to do a fiddle demonstrating it working, sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38d9a/3, but I am unable to get the expected behavior outside of that fiddle.

Comment: @bostaf I updated the question with the information I think you asked for.  So ultimately the query is built through Hibernate, which is broken and why I am looking at this, but until my hand crafted sql is working I cannot concern myself with that.  For the moment I am testing with commandline and MySql Workbench.

Comment: @gwadj give this a try: `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE name LIKE '%@%@%@%%' ESCAPE '@'` (here `@`s could be changed to any symbol)

Comment: Did you say "Hibernate"? The [Hibernate ORM](http://hibernate.org/orm/)? Are you having the issue running the raw SQL query through command line and MySQL workbench OR are you having it running through Hibernate? If it's Hibernate related then you should really show us how you build the queries with Hibernate. I'm sorry if I seem to repeat my questions but I'm really lost on where the problem occurs :)

Comment: @SalmanA The "ESCAPE '@'" query returned the same incorrect (full) results.  I created a new test database in a slightly different way and was able to get the query to work as expected but now I have figure what is wrong with the create database statement (updated original question).

Comment: @bostaf The issue is with all three:  command line, MySQL Workbench, and Hibernate ORM.  Please do not be concerned about the Hibernate portion...  I am much more comfortable with the raw sql.  Anyhow, the problem seems to be with how I creating the database.  Any idea why `create database testdb character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;` would result in the behavior I described?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this appears to be a bug in mysql... it is sometimes impossible to search for consecutive percent signs using `LIKE`. (I was experiencing the same issue you described)

Still not sure what conditions are required to trigger the bug.

One workaround, however, would be to use `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE NAME REGEXP "%%";
```